# Persistent local storage for both Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, indexeddb, html5-filesystem

Looking for advice/options for having persistent local storage using both Firefox and Chrome allowing me to save 50MB+ data. I would be storing dynamic terrain data for a WebGL game, so it wouldn't be necessary for the server to send the whole data every time the player connects. I could just update the old parts.

I thought about using an IndexedDB however Chrome doesn't allow you to increase the quota (unlike Firefox) so I wouldn't be able to store any large data. Chrome allows you to use the FileSystem API which would solve my issue however Firefox does not support it.

So it seems either way it wouldn't work. Is my only option to use the FileSystem API for Chrome and the IndexedDB for Firefox? Does anyone have any better ideas?

This info is what I've read from [Mozilla's Blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/) and [Google's Dev Site](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage) but that may be outdated now, so please feel free to correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly another alternative is the [**application cache**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the other comments about caching and the Chrome/Firefox marketplaces, and they may ultimately be better solutions for you. However, to answer your original question...

IndexedDB in Chrome is definitely not limited to 5 MB. You can store far more than 50 MB in IndexedDB in both Firefox and Chrome, assuming the user has enough hard drive space. Higher amounts of IndexedDB storage are regularly reached in [this game I wrote](http://basketball-gm.com/). On my computer, I currently have over 500 MB stored in IndexedDB in Chrome for that one domain.

You did correctly link to https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage and it is quite confusing, but as I understand it, basically the upper limit is 10% of the free space on the hard drive. Another caveat described on that page is that IndexedDB is technically "temporary" storage that the browser might delete if space is running low, but in practice this seems to rarely happen (YMMV).

Answer (score 1):

localStorage is limited to 5 MB (I think this was on Chrome) and you can request more space for every new 5 MB through dialog boxes.

Both localStorage and IndexedDb are created for interactive data. Because it looks like the data is not modified on the client-side your options are

- Using the [application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) (as mentioned in the comment)
- Serving the data with [cache forever HTTP headers](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?csw=1) (like 10 years), have unique URLs for new resource versions and let the browser re-download the data when it goes out of the cache (recommended)
- Deploy your HTML5 application as a web app, downloads available from Chrome Store and Firefox Marketplace